# How to add laravel multiple required_if (like AND Logical)

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

How to add laravel multiple required_if (like AND Logical) at Laravel Validation. I want to required `'featured_img' if (pagetype == '2' and featured == '1')`

I try this one :

```
'featured_img'   => 'required_if:pagetype,2|required_if:featured,1|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png',
```

but this validation make 'featured_img' required though one of them false (it is like logical "OR". i want make it like "AND" logical)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use custom validation like :

```
$validator->sometimes('featured_img', 'required', function($request) {
    return ($request->pagetype == '2' && $request->featured == '1')
});
```

Take a look at **[Conditionally Adding Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)**.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

$validator->sometimes('featured_img','required',function($request){
         return ($request->pagetype == "2" && $request->featured == "1");
        });